# Is conditional expectation commutative?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$. My intuition is that the conditional expectation $E[E[X|Y]|Z]$ does not necessarily equal $E[E[X|Z]|Y]$, and neither necessarily equals $E[X|Y,Z]$. However, I am having trouble finding a counter-example. Could someone give me a hint as to where to begin (or whether my intuition is right in the first place)? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad! I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Here is a counterexample: take $X$ and $\epsilon$ two independent random variables with $\mathbb{P}(\epsilon = 1) = 1-\mathbb{P}(\epsilon=-1) = p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X= \pm 1) = 1/2$. Define $Y = X$ and $Z = \epsilon X$. Then we can show that $E[X|Z] = (2p-1)Z$. Indeed
$$E[X|Z] = \frac{E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = 1}]}{\mathbb{P}(Z=1)} \mathbf{1}_{Z = 1} + \frac{E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = -1}]}{\mathbb{P}(Z=-1)} \mathbf{1}_{Z = -1}.$$
Then $$E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = 1}] = E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = 1}\mathbf{1}_{\epsilon = 1}] + E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = 1}\mathbf{1}_{\epsilon = -1}] = E[X \mathbf{1}_{X = 1}\mathbf{1}_{\epsilon = 1}] + E[X \mathbf{1}_{X = -1}\mathbf{1}_{\epsilon = -1}] = p - \frac{1}{2} $$
by independence, and $$E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = -1}] =  E[X (1-\mathbf{1}_{Z = 1})] = E[X] - E[X \mathbf{1}_{Z = 1}] =  \frac{1}{2} - p.$$
It is easy to show that $\mathbb{P}(Z= \pm 1) = 1/2$, so that 
$$E[X|Z] = (2p-1)\mathbf{1}_{Z = 1} - (2p-1)\mathbf{1}_{Z = -1} = (2p-1)Z.$$
Now 
$$E\left[ E[X|Z] \middle| Y\right] = E[(2p-1)Z|Y] = (2p-1) E[\epsilon X|X] = (2p-1)X \, E[\epsilon] = (2p-1)^2 X$$
where I used the independence in the third equality. On the other hand
$$E[E[X|Y]|Z] = E[X | Z] = (2p-1) Z = (2p-1) \epsilon X.$$
Clearly $E\left[ E[X|Z] \middle| Y\right]$ and $E[E[X|Y]|Z]$ cannot be equal if $p \neq 1/2$ since they do not take the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $E[\text{anything}\mid Z]$ is a function of $Z$.  So if $Y$ and $Z$ are not functions of each other, $E[E[X\mid Y]\mid Z]$ and $E[E[X \mid Z]\mid Y]$ are typically not equal.  Examples are easy to construct.  Try e.g. $X = Y + Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are correlated normal random variables.

Comment: Yeah right! Sorry I should have thought that. Thanks!